# word for a light "so bright it's painful"

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, idiom-request

Is there an adjective expressing the feeling of light that is so bright it hurts in the eyes?

I'm looking for a synonym word that could be used metaphorically as something like "awfully clear".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you describe it as a [**blinding**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blinding) (or “blindingly bright”) light.

EDIT: somehow I missed that you were looking for a metaphor. I agree with @userr2684291 that “blindingly obvious” (or “blindingly clear”) are common expressions that might be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks! So can I use it metaphorically? Like it's "blindingly clear"?

Comment: @Probably Yes. [*Blindingly obvious*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/blindingly) is a very common phrase, if that's what you wanna use instead (not exactly the same meaning, though).

Comment: I think “blindingly clear” and “blindingly obvious” have more or less the same meaning. “Obvious” is just a stronger word than “clear”. Another related expression is “painfully clear” (or “painfully obvious”).

Comment: @Mixolydian Why would "painfully clear" (or “painfully obvious”) convey the meaning of what author is asking? It doesn't sound right. Could you explain?

Comment: Both “blindingly clear/obvious” and “painfully clear/obvious” are common expressions that basically mean “extremely clear, so much so that it hurts”. “Blinding” and “painful” both describe things that hurt (I am sure becoming blinded by something is not a pleasant sensation). Of course “blinding” refers to an assault on the eyes in particular, but I think if used metaphorically it need not refer only to things that one literally sees with one’s eyes.